# Change Default Localhost IP address (127.0.0.1) of an express (node.js) Server

Tags: node.js, express

How can I change the default localhost IP address (127.0.0.1) of an express (node.js) server? I am developing a web site interacting with a Geth (Ethereum) private Network which already uses that localhost IP address, and thus there is a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just set the port for the express server to run on something different than the ethereum node?  Being on the same IP shouldn't be an issue, but if they are running the same port, that would be an issue.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. This is what I thought, but I am receiving the following error even when using a different port: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8080 Perhaps I am missing something else...

Comment: Answer: I had to run sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp in order to kill the process already running for some reason, and then using a different port number was working.